# How to store a list of String in MongoDB using Java/Springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

So I want to simply store a list like this in MongoDB.

```
[
    {
        "1": "byCharity"
    },
    {
        "2": "byProduct"
    }
]
```

I have a Repository and a controller class which look like this

```
public interface SearchTypeRepository extends MongoRepository<String,Integer> {

}
```

Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/SearchType")
public class SearchTypeController {
    @Autowired
    private SearchTypeRepository searchTypeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/AddSearchType")
    public String addSearchType(@QueryParam("searchType") String searchType) {
        searchTypeRepository.save(searchType);
        return searchType;
    }

    @GetMapping("/GetSearchTypes")
    public List getSearchTypes() {
        return searchTypeRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

However when on class instantiation I receive an error like this.

```
Error creating bean with name 'searchTypeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchTypeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchTypeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
```

All help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can store this type of **json** in MongoDB using following steps:

Make a POJO like this :

```
public class MyPojo {

private List<Map<String, String>> message;

//Getters
//Setters
}
```

Add your objects to map

**Note: Every time create a new Map instance to store object in map.**

Change your repository

```
public interface SearchTypeRepository extends MongoRepository<String,Integer> {}
```

to

```
public interface SearchTypeRepository extends MongoRepository<String,MyPojo> {}
```

and perform save operation.